# I want to converting an .obj/.gltf file into .pdf?

Tags: pdf, converters, gltf

I'm new to this platform. I have no idea on this, Please help on this. When I started searching on this I have get only the online conversion tools. I need to do this in offline

Online tools are that I have used is
https://products.aspose.app/3d/conversion/obj-to-pdf

I want to convert the **.glTF** file or **.obj** file to **.pdf**. Any refers are available means please share.

Comment: What you probably need is a tool to render a screenshot of a glTF or OBJ file to an image, and then make a PDF from that screenshot.  You may have better luck searching for those as separate tools in a two-step process.

Comment: However, recommending tools is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow... This question is likely to get closed, as a result.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I don't need any tool. I need code to convert it.

Comment: I don't think you will find that answer on Stack Overflow. We can help you find problems in your own code, but cannot write complex tools for you. Maybe start with https://github.com/Shopify/screenshot-glb? If you can get a screenshot you should have a much easier time getting a PDF after that.

Comment: @SanthoshkumarV, have you found the solution ?